# csv file is not recognized in junit5

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I'm trying write some tests for a class with the help of junit 5.I have imported the dependencies using Maven
but when I'm try to import a csv file to use as test case using annotation @CsvFileSource(resources = "/testlist.csv")
I get this error

```
org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Classpath resource [/testlist.csv] does not exist
```

this is the code I'm running

```
 package com.faezeh.shayesteh;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;
public class MultipleOperationParamTest {
    @ParameterizedTest

    @CsvFileSource(resources = "/testlist.csv")
    void testMultipleOpWithCsvFileSrc(int operand, int data, int result){
        MultiplyOperation multop = new MultiplyOperation(operand);
        int actual = multop.operate(data);
        Assertions.assertEquals(result,actual);

    }
}
```

and this is how my directories are sorted
[image]

I need to mention when I'm not using Maven as framework and sort my directories as below it works fine and there's no problem
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the CSV file resides within the `com.faezeh.shayesteh` package, you have to specify the corresponding classpath location:

```
@CsvFileSource(resources = "/com/faezeh/shayesteh/testlist.csv")
```

Have a look at `target/test-classes/`, this is the test classpath root (`/`). If you put your CSV file inside `src/test/resources/`, you will find it directly under the root path. This way you could stick to `resource = "/testlist.csv"`.

Answer (score 1):

In case your file is in the test resource folder do not forget to add `/`

```
@CsvFileSource(resources = "testlist.csv")
```

Change to following:

```
@CsvFileSource(resources = "/testlist.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case **IntelliJ** just didn't register the new csv file in the test /resources fast enough